# What is the difference between 納入 and 支払?

Tags: pragmatics

My water bill reads 納入 is due, but the credit card bill says お支払い. What is the difference between these two terms?

Comment: By credit card bill do you mean the 領収書 you get in every other shop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this situation, 「納入{のうにゅう}」 and 「お支払{しはら}い」 practically mean the same thing -- the "***payment***".

「納入」 is more Bureaucratese than Japanese.  It is exclusively used to refer to payments in the public sector.  Schools, public or private, also tend to use the term in their poor attempt to not sound "commercial" when asking for tuition payments.

「お支払い」 is used widely in the private sector where it would not matter if that term sounded "commercial".  Everyone knows credit card companies make mega-yen.

Answer (score 0):

The Japanese shop would like to be polite to send "納品書 list of item delivered" instead of "請求書 billing", sounds elegant, doesn't it?

It should be officially "請求書 invoice" and "領収書 receipt"